# Binary data corrupted from php to AS3 via http

Tags: php, actionscript-3, http

I'm trying to retrieve binary data using AS3 from a PHP server via HTTP, but very often (~50%) a few bytes arrive corrupted.

---

PHP snippets:

```
header('Content-Type:binary/octet-stream;');

echo $this->page;
```

AS3 snippet:

```
var resp:int=data.readByte();
var user_id:uint=data.readUnsignedInt();
var anon_id:uint=data.readUnsignedInt();
var token:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
data.readBytes(token,0,16);
```

---

Examples, with the sent data in the first line, and the received data in the second line (spaces added for readability):

```
01000000110000000095cb4bca40fb d0bb ab7bdd15b3e973c7
01000000110000000095cb4bca40fb 3b   ab7bdd15b3e973c7

010000001200000000bb5c4c55af caa9e9afd6 a7f550748b61
010000001200000000bb5c4c55af a9e9af     a7f550748b61

010000001400000000e191ffbc222d239debe 8d69 0d93b7ca4
010000001400000000e191ffbc222d239debe 89   0d93b7ca4

0100000017000000002e1b75 db89 8a1a cd86 f05a8bf07c592b
0100000017000000002e1b75 c9   8a1a 46   f05a8bf07c592b

010000001a00000000b4d72a3a8cd b944 5d0559072d8d16583
010000001a00000000b4d72a3a8cd 44   5d0559072d8d16583

010000001e000000007 bc8a 377bd9feab432260d43db4a42ab
010000001e000000007 b2   377bd9feab432260d43db4a42ab
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I still have no idea what was happening, I dodged the problem transmitting hex encoded data in plain/text.

Answer (score -1):

There is not enough code shown. But, you may be suffering from inadvertent character encoding of binary data being treated as text.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would care to offer a better hypothesis?