# Binary Data from PHP to Angular 6 via http

Tags: php, angular, binary-data

the goal is to make a http request (empty) from Angular 7 to PHP to receive binary data in Angular for the use with protobuf3.
More specifically, the binary data (encoded like described here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) in PHP (source) is encapsulated in a string, while the goal in Angular is a Uint8Array.

Therefore, I currently have the following working code:

PHP Code (a simple ProcessWire root template):

```
header('Content-Type: application/b64-protobuf');
…
echo base64_encode($response->serializeToString());
```

Angular:

```
let res = this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  res.subscribe((data) => {

  let binary_string = atob(data);
  let len = binary_string.length;
  let bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  let parsedResponse = pb.Response.deserializeBinary(bytes)      
})
```

As you can see I encode the data as base64 before sending it. So, it is not as efficient as it could be, because base64 reduces the amount of information per character. I tried already quite a lot to get binary transmission working, but in the end the data always gets corrupted, i.e. the variable `bytes` is not identical to the argument of `base64_encode`. 
But still, according to some sources (e.g. [PHP write binary response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022213/php-write-binary-response), [Binary data corrupted from php to AS3 via http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913260/binary-data-corrupted-from-php-to-as3-via-http) (nobody says it would not be possible)) it should be possible.

**So my question is: What must change to directly transfer binary data? Is it even possible?**

What have I tried?

- using different headers, such as
  `header('Content-Type:binary/octet-stream;');` or using Blob in Angular.
- I also tried to remove `base64_encode` from the PHP Code and `atob`
  from the Angular Code. The result: the content of the data is modified between `serializeToString` and `deserializeBinary(bytes)`, which is not desired.
- I checked for possible characters before `<?php`

Specifications:

- PHP 7.2.11
- Apache 2.4.35
- Angular 7.0.2

If further information is needed, just let me know in the comments. I am eager to provide it. Thanks.

Comment: "the data always gets corrupted" what does this mean? Also, I would assume the results of `$response->serializeToString()` would be a string, not "binary data."

Comment: string containing data encoded at binary level (described here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding); "the data gets corrupted" means "the serialization of the data is different from what ends up being in the bytes array in Angular" -> Ill extend my question.

Comment: But you're just echoing a string from PHP. You're not making any attempt to encode it in any sort of binary format. Is this your question? If so, it's too broad. Show us what you've tried and how it hasn't worked out.

Comment: Like I wrote, I tried e.g. `header('Content-Type:binary/octet-stream;');` which, combined with echo, should return the string/data as it is. According to the response to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022213/php-write-binary-response strings and byte arrays are the same anyways. In the end a hex analysis showed some additional/changed/removed bytes.

Comment: All that does is change the value of an HTTP header. It doesn't change what data is sent.

Comment: good to know - I was not aware of that. I added another example, which should make the problem more obvious. (I also have edited the previous comment)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding this whole thing, the problem is that you want to send data from PHP in a proprietary binary format, and you are making no attempt to do so. If you want it to look like what's described at that Google link, you'll need to write PHP code to do that.

Comment: The function `serializeToString()` already does already convert to the format which is described at the google link (JFYI json serialization is also possible with `serializeJsonToString()`). Else it certainly would not work with base64.